# eonasdan bootstrap-datetimepicker 4 show years on reopen

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [eonasdan bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) is there any way to enable the widget on reopen in years instead of calendar?
The first open with `viewMode: 'years'` doesn't apply on reopen.
Thank you.

Comment: As I can remember, there is an API to set options dynamically after initialization (first open). Try to set this option before opening. See the documentation for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using v4 you can call the function `viewMode` to set it back.

`$('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').viewMode('years')`

I'd listen for the change event if you want to set the view after the user makes a change.

You might post an issue on the github page as a feature request for the view mode to go back after a change

Comment: Thank you Eonasdan, I apologize for the late reply.